# How do I add/import less files in Meteor package

Tags: meteor, import, less, package

I have created a package in which I placed less files and then add these files in package file but I didn't find these files in resource in browser.
My package structure is:

> package -> client -> autocomplet -> autocomplet.import.less, autocomplet.js, autocomplet.html

And in package.js file:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.use('templating', 'client');
    api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');
    api.addFiles('./client/autocomplete/autocomplete.html');
    api.addFiles('./client/autocomplete/autocomplete.js');
    api.addFiles('./client/autocomplete/autocomplete.css');
});
```

Comment: And where's your `.less` file in that package?

Answer (score 2):

Kyll's comment pointed out one of the issues. You need to both use `less` to import the less files, and also add the files themselves. Also note that `./` is not necessary because the paths are already relative to the location of `package.js`. Something like the following:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');

    api.use('templating', 'client');
    api.use('less');

    api.addFiles('client/autocomplete/autocomplete.html');
    api.addFiles('client/autocomplete/autocomplete.js');
    api.addFiles('client/autocomplete/autocomplete.import.less');
});
```

P.S. Have you checked out the [autocomplete](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/autocomplete) package? (Disclaimer: I wrote this package.)

Comment: thanks for your comments Andrew, after adding api.use('less'); this all goes well but when we use this package we have to import that less files by adding path to relative to packages and then less file path inside package. like '../../../packages/mypackage/client/autocomplete/autocomplete.import.less'. Is there another way to do it as i don't think it right way to do it.